# nested layout in sinatra

Tags: ruby, layout, sinatra

In a sinatra app, We have `views/layout.erb` as the top layout. But some pages would share a common look only for a certain channel but also need the globally shared parts in `views/layout.erb`. Is there a way to define a nested layout which use `views/layout.erb` as its parent layout?

Answer (score 1):

What might be the easiest way is to have the specific layout also include the global layout, and set that specific layout as the default for the routes you need.

In specific.erb

```
<%= erb :layout %>                      # if you are using Sinatra 1.1 and up
<%= erb :layout, :layout => false %>    # if you are using Sinatra prior to 1.1
```

Using a before filter would allow you to set that in one location, if that is possible.

```
before '/special' do
  @default_layout = :specific
end
```

Otherwise, just use that same line `@default_layout = :specific` in your route.

Comment: Where should I put `<%= yield %>` in specific.erb then? I followed these instructions and it does not work. I put `<%= erb :layout %>` and `<%= yield %>` in specific.erb and that leads to an error of "no block given (yield)" in `<%= erb :layout %>`.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, I have always used haml. You might be having an issue because there is a `yield` in layout.erb. Try removing the yield from layout and see if that works (although it will break the standard pages, it will at least be progress). You would want to yield from specific.erb just after the main layout, I'm guessing.